# Could less show the viewed proportion of text file?

Tags: linux, editing

As the title implies, when I am browsing text file,I would like to know the current viewed porportion of the whole text file.

I know that with -N option,we could turn on the line numbers,but how  could  I make less display the line number of the whole text file?

thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you open a file with less then pressing Ctrl-g will display the current line number, total lines and percentage as well as shown below:

lines 51-100/185 byte 3228/5886 54%  (press RETURN)

Comment: thanks.after revisiting the man page,manage to find it and get the other two equal command ':f' and '='.sorry for this.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work through pipes, neither with the -M or -m parameter from the other answer. For example `wdiff version1.txt version2.txt | colordiff | less -RM` does not show the percentage. Let me know if someone has a solution or workaround for this.
Update: the solution is to add +Gg like another answer explained.

Answer (score 24):

Do you mean like with the `-M` switch?

Comment: That's exactly what I want!

Comment: Or `-m` if line-number is not necessary.

Comment: Do you have an idea if there is a solution or workaround to display the percentage when using pipes? For example I cannot see the percentage for a colored diff with this command: `wdiff version1.txt version2.txt | colordiff | less -RM`
Update: the solution is to add +Gg like another answer explained.

Answer (score 7):

Just expanding a wee bit on the previous answers. Command line:

```
less -M +Gg
```

does the following:

**-M** Show current position within the file on the prompt
**+Gg** Run commands `G` (go to the end of the file) and `g` (go back to the beginning of the file)

If `less` is reading from stdin, which happens when `man` is showing a man page, it doesn't know the total number of lines in the file in advance, so that it can properly calculate its position. Therefore, `+Gg` is necessary so that `less` can get the total number of lines, and thus calculate the current position as a percentage.

I found it useful to set these variables in *~/.bashrc*:

```
export LESS+='-M'
export MANPAGER='less +Gg'
```

`LESS` will ensure that all invocations of `less` will show the current position on the prompt, and `MANPAGER` will ensure that `less` will be able to get the total number of lines in the man page, which `less` will then show on the prompt. It seemed to be more sensible **not** to include `+Gg` in `LESS` to prevent `less` from trying to go to the end of potentially large piped input. If that's necessary, one can always run the commands `G` and `g` manually.

Comment: +1 for the manual way, press `Gg`

Comment: Why do put a plus sign "LESS+" in your example? Shouldn't it be enough to just write "export LESS='M'"?

Comment: @d-b, LESS+='-M' will append option -M to whatever options have been previously set for LESS

Answer (score 6):

`less -M +Gg`

for not very big files it's OK, because `+G` (`G` command) go till the end of file

Comment: Great for `$MANPAGER` though! See `man man`.

Comment: Great for `colordiff` too! E.g.: `wdiff version1.txt version2.txt | colordiff | less -RM +Gg`

Comment: Note to my previous comment: I had to use `wdiff -n` to make `colordiff` work correctly if multiline text was added.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `moar`, which does what you want out of the box:
https://github.com/walles/moar

`moar` is designed to be simple to switch to from `less`.

`moar` also comes with syntax highlighting input by default, nice search, word wrapping and lots of other things missing from `less`.

[image: Screenshot showing line numbers]

Disclaimer: I wrote `moar` so of course I like it!

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl-g` works, just press `=` will do the same and quicker.

@Jichao has mentioned this, just post this answer for others to find easyer.

by the way, including the man page part

`=` or `^G` or `:f`

> Prints  some  information  about the file being viewed, including its name and the line number and byte offset of the bottom line being displayed.  If possible, it also prints the length of the file, the number of lines in the file and the percent of the file above the last displayed line.